# Como documentos devueltos por mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

Estoy intentando manipular un documentos que me devuelve una consulta a mongoDB a traves de mongoose pero logro conseguirlo. Estoy desarrollando con Node.js con framework Koa y Mongoose como ODM.

El código es :

```
const Router = require('koa-router');
const RestaurantModel = require('models/restaurant.model');

class RestaurantRouter{

    static async get(ctx,next){
        ctx.body = await RestaurantModel.find();
    }

    static async getById(ctx){
        ctx.body='get';
    }
}

const router = new Router({prefix:'/restaurant'});

router.get('/', RestaurantRouter.get);
router.get('/:id', RestaurantRouter.getById);

module.exports = router;
```

Necesitaría Poder manipular el documento que me devuelve RestaurantModel.find(); y embeberlo dentro de otro documento mas grande y mandarlo al body de la response, algo así como

```
ctx.body = await {feature : RestaurantModel.find()};
```

No encuentro la manera ya que RestaurantModel.find() no devuelve el documento en sí sino un objeto Query del que no consigo sacar el documento.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias!

Comment: Te recomiendo dividir tu aplicación en capas, abstraerlas unas de otras para evitar que una capa tenga múltiples responsabilidades (ver [Principio de Responsabilidad Única](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica)). Organiza tu app en 3 capas: Modelo, Repositorio y Manejadores/Controladores. La capa Repositorio son funciones/clases que se encargan de obtener los datos de los modelos y realizar funciones adicionales si es el caso, de esta manera los handlers quedan "abstraídos" de esos procesos, permitiéndote escalar mucho mejor.

Comment: Gracias! lo tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Koa, el *Content-Type* es implícito de acuerdo al valor que le asignes a `ctx.body`. En tu caso, debes de asignarle un objeto para que te devuelva un JSON. No veo ningún problema en tu caso, salvo por detalles de arquitectura. Solo necesitas envolver lo que te devuelve el modelo en otro objeto:

```
ctx.body = {
  feature: await RestaurantModel.find()
};
```

Lo que producirá una respuesta como.

```
{
  "feature": [
    { ... },
    { ... },
    { ... }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Estaba colocando sintacticamente la palabra await donde no correspondía, delante del igual `ctx.body = await {feature : RestaurantModel.find()};` en lugar de `ctx.body = {feature : await RestaurantModel.find()};` . No entiendo muy bien por qué, lo miraré. ¿A que te refieres con detalles de arquitectura?. Graicas!!

Comment: Si te sirvió mi respuesta no olvides marcarla. Sobre tu pregunta, me refiero por arquitectura a lo que comenté en tu pregunta.